# How to solve " !!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!! (parcel size = 112)" problem?

Tags: java, android

I'm creating a small app using Java in Android Studio.

I have a `edittext` which is for the url input and there's an Intent, and it's the only intent of the whole app, for it to pass the url to the next activity. But I can't get the text input. Once I click on the `edittext`, I got this error:

```
!!! FAILED BINDER TRANSACTION !!!  (parcel size = 112)
2023-05-15 18:36:49.421 25271-25271 InputMetho...ionWrapper com.example.itube                    W  IME died

android.os.DeadObjectException: Transaction failed on small parcel; remote process probably died
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transactNative(Native Method)
    at android.os.BinderProxy.transact(BinderProxy.java:571)
    at com.android.internal.view.IInputMethodSession$Stub$Proxy.viewClicked(IInputMethodSession.java:341)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodSessionWrapper.viewClicked(InputMethodSessionWrapper.java:119)
    at android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager.viewClicked(InputMethodManager.java:2284)
    at android.widget.TextView.viewClicked(TextView.java:13303)
    at android.widget.TextView.onTouchEvent(TextView.java:11212)
    at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:14540)
```

This is the code:

```
//       get video url
        if (binding.url.getText() != null) {
            videoUrl = binding.url.getText().toString();
        }

//        play button
        binding.playBtn.setOnClickListener(view -> {
            Log.v("url pre", videoUrl);
//            Intent toPlay = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), PlayActivity.class);
//            toPlay.putExtra("url",  videoUrl);
//            startActivity(toPlay);
        });
```

I can't get the result of `Log.v()` either.